# Trying to select a range of cells from one column and paste it below the last filled cell in another column

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I am trying to merge two sheets. I'd need to copy a range from one column like to the next empty cell of a column on another sheet. I've tried around five methods I've found on the internet and none of them worked so far, even though it seems like it should be an easy operation. I have the following code that gives

> Copy method of Range class failed

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub gMerge()
Dim ssaw As Worksheet
Dim trckr As Worksheet
Set ssaw = Sheets("SSAW_DATA")
Set trckr = Sheets("SQL_DATA_FEED")

'ssaw.Range("G2", Selection.end(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=ssaw.Range("H2")

ssaw.Range("C2", Selection.end(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=trckr.Range("B2").end(xlDown).Row + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: If there is nothing in B3 this will try to paste the selection in the last row on the sheet.  start at the bottom of the sheet and use (xlUp).

Comment: Column `B` is filled `B1:B362`, it has a header. I tried swapping `trckr.Range("B2")` to simple `("B")` to no avail

Comment: just tested `(xlUp)` gives the same error

Comment: `ssaw.Range("C2", ssaw.cells(rows.count,3).end(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=trckr.cells(Rows.count,2).end(xlup).Row + 1`

Comment: tried your code, same error, I just don't understand what the issue is

Comment: You are using `Selection` in your code but you haven't selected anything. I wouldn't use `Selection` anyway. Try using `Cells` or `Range`

Comment: did you use the full line? I also changed the copied range

Comment: Yeah I used the full line, just tried it again.

Comment: Are you just trying to copy the range C2 to last row to the other sheet starting from B2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range + 1 is throwing you.

Try defining the last row outside of the destination, so you can paste to a known cell location, such as:

```
dim lr as long, lr2 as Long
With Sheets("SQL_DATA_FEED")
    lr = .cells(.rows.count,2).end(xlup).row
    lr2 = ssaw.cells(ssaw.rows.count,3).end(xlup).row
    ssaw.Range(ssaw.cells(2,"C"),ssaw.cells(lr2,"C")).Copy Destination:=.cells(lr+1,2)
End With
```

Comment: Well at least it's a different error message `Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed` Even though these are just bog standard columns with characters in them.

Comment: @Rhyfelwr try now; i changed the With from using trckr to the actual sheet name.

Comment: Same error, this is slowly driving me insane haha, I've been bashing my head against the wall for around 3 hours now.

Comment: @Rhyfelwr Take a look now... you used Range("C2", cells...) which is inappropriate syntax.  you need "C2:C" & findlastrow  to be correct... i changed it to use .Cells() structure

Comment: Yep this one did the trick. I'll stick with this solution, thank you!